# Python line is too long, how can i make it more readable?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, readability

```
for pic,fn,xoff in [(self.PNew,self.New,0),(self.POpen,self.Open,0),(self.PSave,self.Save,0),(self.POrigin,self.SetOrigin,20),(self.PFiducial,self.SetFiducial,0),(self.PLine,self.AddLine,20),(self.PPoint,self.AddPoint,0),(self.PMove,self.AddMove,0),(self.PCircle,self.AddCircle,0),(self.PCall,self.AddCall,0)]: Button(ButtonRow,image=pic,command=fn).pack(side=LEFT,padx=(xoff,0))
```

Comment: Holy mother of linebreaks, ca. 380 chars o.O

Comment: i know hehe, i'm wondering if maybe theres another way of doing the same thing shorter.. maybe taking out the 'self.'s somehow, or change my function and picture to be more similar in title and use strings.. i have no idea.. thats why i posted here i suppose :P

Comment: In general, the backslash lets you manually wrap a line of code.

Comment: @Nik: Using blackslashes is usually a bad idea. Easy to miss and must be the very last character of the line (luckily you get an error if not, but still). The three kind of brackets remove linebreaks inside themselves implicitly and in spite of trailing whitespace, and they're much harder to miss.

Comment: Absolutely true. Just giving an alternative.

Comment: Here's [good advice](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#long-lines-continuations) on how to handle different kinds of long lines in Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
items = [
    (self.PNew, self.New, 0),
    (self.POpen, self.Open, 0),
    (self.PSave, self.Save, 0),
    (self.POrigin, self.SetOrigin, 20),
    (self.PFiducial, self.SetFiducial, 0),
    (self.PLine, self.AddLine, 20),
    (self.PPoint, self.AddPoint, 0),
    (self.PMove, self.AddMove, 0),
    (self.PCircle, self.AddCircle, 0),
    (self.PCall, self.AddCall, 0)
]
for pic, fn, xoff in items: 
    Button(ButtonRow, image=pic, command=fn).pack(side=LEFT, padx=(xoff, 0))
```

Comment: Could use spaces after the commas (yes, all of them) as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could make it into a function...

```
def add_button(pic, fn, xoff=0):
    Button(ButtonRow, image=pic, command=fn).pack(side=LEFT, padx=(xoff, 0))

add_button(self.PNew, self.New)
add_button(self.POpen, self.Open)
add_button(self.PSave, self.Save)
add_button(self.POrigin, self.SetOrigin, 20)
add_button(self.PFiducial, self.SetFiducial)
add_button(self.PLine, self.AddLine, 20)
add_button(self.PPoint, self.AddPoint)
add_button(self.PMove, self.AddMove)
add_button(self.PCircle, self.AddCircle)
add_button(self.PCall, self.AddCall)
```

Comment: much cleaner to have an items list i think